# SQL Nested CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I change this `SELECT` statement to create an `adj_b2` column that depends on the same condition as `adj_a2` and an `adj_b3` that depends on a different condition?

```
 SELECT CASE
        WHEN c.1 > 5
            THEN COALESCE(a.2,0)*2 
            ELSE COALESCE(a.2,0)                
    END as adj_a2, a.*, b.*, c.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use three separate `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN c.1 > 5
      THEN COALESCE(a.2,0)*2 
    ELSE COALESCE(a.2,0)                
  END as adj_a2,
  CASE
    WHEN c.1 > 5
      THEN COALESCE(b.2,0)*2 
    ELSE COALESCE(b.2,0)                
  END as adj_b2,
  CASE
    WHEN c.2 < 42
      THEN COALESCE(a.2,0)*c.3 
    ELSE COALESCE(b.2,0)*c.4                
  END as adj_b3,
  a.*,
  b.*,
  c.*
```